# Chmod/chown permissions question

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have 2 users, GM and FTP. I want GM to have read access, and FTP to have all access. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first understand that permissions are file-based.

If you want file `/var/example.txt` readable by `GM` and writable by `FTP`, you could set its owner to `FTP` (`chown FTP /var/example.txt`) and set its permissions to `644` (`chmod 644 /var/example.txt` or `chmod u+rw,o+r /var/example.txt`).  This will make the file readable by everyone but only writable by FTP.

If you only want `GM` to have read access, you will need to put both users in the same `group` and set the permission to `640`.

For more details on file permissions, refer to the [`chmod` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with *nix file permissions, use file's acl if your fs supports it. eg.
`setfacl -d -m u:GM:rx /directory`
`setfacl -d -m u:FTP:rwx /directory`

Use `tune2fs -l /dev/sdX | grep acl` to check your fs.